# Angular ng-class affect multiple elements

Tags: angularjs

I have a code that I generate using Python's Mako templates:

```
<ul class="list-group">
        % for t in list:
        <li class="list-group-item">
            <div
                ng-class="hover ? 'btn btn-xs btn-default' : ''"
                ng-mouseenter="hover = true"
                ng-mouseleave="hover = false"> ${list.data} </div>
        </li>
        % endfor
    </ul>
```

All I want is that the row I'm hovering of - will be converted to a button.

Problem is that I see a list of rows ,but when the mouse hover on one of the elements - *all* elements are affected instead of the specific `<li>` element I was hovering of , like all the text inside all the rows are converted to buttons.... any idea what am I missing ?

Comment: What is `% for t in list:` ?  That doesn't seem like standard angular.  Where's the `ng-repeat`?

Comment: what version of Angular are you running?

Comment: @ryanyuyu I'm guessing that's from Python's Mako templates. Ricky why are you using Mako instead of Angular's `ng-repeat`?

Comment: Running 1.3.8, and I said above - this is rendered via Python Mako Templates lib ... not angular, I receive this HTML using $http and then I compile it so it would communicate as a real AngularJS code

Comment: Can you post a Plunkr that reproduces the bug? I represented your code in Angular and am not seeing anything wrong. http://plnkr.co/edit/O6DnQ9Lhhwb55byC4ov7?p=linter

Comment: Is hover a single property, or a property for each individual `<li>`?

Comment: reproduced at: http://plnkr.co/edit/1T1moaTuFvH2rMbqduoT?p=info

Comment: @ryanyuyu for each <div> inside every <li>, I hope I created it individually, or at least - that's what I want ... don't want them all

Comment: Ricky I think you accidentally linked to the Plunker I created.

Comment: Haha ... yes, edited my comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/1T1moaTuFvH2rMbqduoT?p=info

Comment: @MorganPolotan I deliberately removed the ng-repeat and created the elements myself, since this is how I receive and compile the HTML, the "for loop" logic was already done by Python ( back-end )

Comment: Got it, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your hover variable is being assigned in the global scope. Using `ng-repeat` fixes this because each template instance [gets its own scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat).

To fix this without `ng-repeat` you can namespace the hover property within the list object, like in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/O6DnQ9Lhhwb55byC4ov7?p=preview).